# Get current user full name and id in Javacript page

Tags: apex, remote-action

In my application that uses JS the user can click a button to create a new record, the goal is to give them a column in a table where they can select an active user to assign the record to. So i built a remote action that queries all the active users into a list and then the JS functions take over and that list is now searchable in this field which works great.

Example:

```
 @RemoteAction
public static List<User> getActiveUsers() {

    String query = 'SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE';
    return Database.query(query);
}
```

Example:

```
<tr>
 <td>Owner</td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOwner" placeholder="Type Owner Name"
         bs-options="user as user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName for user in userCollection | filter:$viewValue" bs-typeahead required/>
</td>
```

Now I want to take it one step further that when the page is first loaded the default is the current user.

So this makes me think I need another remote action to get the current user's information.

Example:

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<User> getCurrentUser() {
    String query = 'SELECT id, FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Id = $User.Id';
    return Database.query(query);
}
```

This compiles and lets me save however, when I run it through anonymous apex to see if a result returns I get the error:

> no viable alternative at character '$'

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: `:UserInfo.getUserId()`?

Comment: doh! that did it.

Comment: There's also `UserInfo.getName()` which would return the current user's full name without the need for a query. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just merge the `$User` global variables into your markup:

```
var runningUserId = "{!$User.Id}"
```

Or you can use `UserInfo` methods in `Apex`. *Don't use dynamic queries unless static queries won't work for you*.

```
@RemoteAction
public static User getCurrentUser()
{
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
}
```

Comment: That's solid advice.